# Hyperlinks are not working n the PDF converted using phantom-html-to-pdf

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, npm

I've used **phantom-html-to-pdf** npm module to convert HTML to PDF file. But the hyperlinks which are in the PDF file is not working. Any idea how to make the hyperlinks work?

```
const conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")();

conversion({ html: strPdfBody }, (error, pdf) => {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        const output = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        pdf.stream.pipe(output);
 });
```

As mentioned above, I've passed a string value of the html (strPdfBody) to the node module to convert it to a pdf. PDF conversion is a success. But the hyperlinks are not working in the converted pdf.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example so that people can help? This isn't enough information to provide a response. If this is a code question, please provide the code you are using to make the conversion, otherwise if it is a software question, this isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: I've added the code  snippet I've used.